# Objective-C: How to cast a boolean as an object for use with NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory, casting

I need to cast a boolean as an object, or NSKeyedArchiver throws a memory access error. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Note: I am using the encodeObject: method of NSCoder to encode my boolean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about encodeBool:forKey: instead?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that function was available. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Further to NSD's answer, in a general sense: Cocoa often requires actual objects for various methods.  When the type you have is an ordinal type, such as `int`, `BOOL`, or `float`, you can wrap it in an `NSNumber`.  For other types, you may need to wrap it in an `NSValue` or `NSData` (which is essentially an arbitrary binary buffer of a given length).